# Variance Ratio Test in Minitab

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, p-value, minitab

I have two samples, each of size 18 observations. In the first, the SD is 10 and in the second it is 3. I wish to test the hypothesis that the variance ratio is 4, vs. the alternative that it is not 4, using a significance level of 2% (so I have 1% in each side). I got that the two sided limits (critical values) are 0.3085 and 3.242. I also found that the test statistic is 2.778. The CI for the variance ratio is [3.427, 36.021], which includes 4 in it. Using both the CI and the test statistic, my conclusion is not to reject the null hypothesis. I ran the same test in Minitab. The software agreed with me on the CI and on the test statistic, however, the p-value is 0.042. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think there's a contradiction somewhere but there is not.

The p-value is larger than the significance level of 2% so you wouldn't reject the null hypothesis, exactly as you found using critical values and with the confidence interval.

(Is it possible you forgot you were doing a 2% test and compared the p-value with 0.05?)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I have done...how do I make an embarrassed smiley over here? Thank you very much for your quick comment.